# How to restore previous colormap in matlab?

Tags: matlab, colormap

I have some images in some range of numbers. Here's an example of an image:

[image: laplacian]

This is a level in a [Laplacian Pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_pyramid) of an image. (It's not necessary to understand what a Laplacian Pyramid is...)

Now I need to make some operations on those images, and I need to change the colormap for that. I changed it to gray(256) and made the operations i need. So now I have different images in `colormap(gray(256))`.

Now I need to scale back to the previous range. But I don't know the previous range or colormap. I tried saving the colormap before the operations.

I tried this:

```
imwrite(img,colormap(gray(256)),str);
```

but that changed the whole matrix to 255.

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Setting the colormap should not affect the images (i.e. the values in the matrix).  It changes how it's displayed only.  So the real answer depends on whether you just want to display the images (i.e. with something like `imshow(I,[])`), or whether you want to rescale the values in the matrices (i.e. so that `imwrite` works properly).

Comment: I didn't mention that I used `imwrite`: `imwrite(img,colormap(gray(256)),str);` And then re-read the images. So the matrices did change...

Comment: Well that's much more relevant than the code you previously gave. (edited)

Answer (score 1):

```
imwrite(img,colormap(gray(256)),str);
```

`colormap` only sets the color of a `figure`, so you don't need it in `imwrite`.  In fact, it does nothing of value here.  If you pass a map, `gray(256)`, it will write this as an indexed image.  That is, it saves in the file both the values of the pixels and the map which says what those values mean.

However, it doesn't scale the input image to match the colormap neatly.  As stated in the docs:

> If A is an indexed image of data type double or single, then imwrite
>   converts the indices to zero-based indices by subtracting 1 from each
>   element, and then writes the data as uint8. If the data in A is
>   single, convert A to double before writing to a GIF or TIFF file.

What this means is if your `img` contains all values of 256 or above, `imwrite` will subtract one, and write as `uint8`, clipping values over 255 to 255 (and below 0 to 0).  So your image appears as all 255.

You need to first scale `img` to an appropriate range (e.g. record the max and min values of your input matrix - not the `colormap`! - before you do anything to it).  This is just math - e.g. something like `img = img/256` may be all you need.  It is unnecessary to save it with a map in most cases - you're just writing your values as grayscale, you can save them with `imwrite` into a normal image.

`imwrite` generally expects `double` to be in the range of 0 to 1 and `uint8` in the range of 0 to 255. If your values don't match up to this, you will get clipping/"blank" images, etc.

However, because values are stored as integers (`uint8`) in most image formats, I don't see how you can use `imwrite` to save the sort of values you display in your example without losing precision.  You also won't be able to save any negative values.  So it would be best to save your real values in a different format (`*.mat` file, csv, etc.) and save an image if you need it for visualisation, but not for storing calculated values.

Comment: After i scale back, i'll do some other operations so that the result image is in range [0..255]. And only then i'll display the images. This is tested and it works. So there's no need to worry about displaying the images. So you suggest saving min and max, scale `img` to [0..255] (maybe `mod(img,256)`?) make the operations i need, then use min and max to restore to previous range?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the images/results. You show values with negative floats in - those can't be nicely saved/restored through `imwrite`.  (Don't use `mod`, though - that would destroy your data!).  I personally try to avoid such scaling in the case that my values have a physical meaning, save those values in a format that preserves them, and use other methods of automatically scaling on display (e.g. `[]` in `imshow` or `imagesc`).